# App Store Review Scraping HTTPSConnection Error

Tags: web-scraping, app-store, screen-scraping

When i run this script, i get the error. I try to solve using sleep time between calls because i want to scrape a lot of reviews. However, it doesn't solve my problem.
Here is what I have tried and it didn't work:

```
import pandas as pd
from app_store_scraper import AppStore
import random

app_ = AppStore(country="us",app_name="Peet's Coffee: Earn Rewards", app_id = 1059865964)

app_.review(how_many=10000,
            sleep=random.randint(25,30)
           )

pets = pd.DataFrame(app_.reviews)
pets.to_excel("Peet's Coffee.xlsx")
```

Please advise how to deal with this error, or maybe there is another way to scrape App Store reviews.

Error:

```
2022-03-11 11:33:44,617 [INFO] Base - Initialised: AppStore('us', 'peet-s-coffee-earn-rewards', 1059865964)
2022-03-11 11:33:44,618 [INFO] Base - Ready to fetch reviews from: https://apps.apple.com/us/app/peet-s-coffee-earn-rewards/id1059865964
2022-03-11 11:34:12,743 [INFO] Base - [id:1059865964] Fetched 20 reviews (20 fetched in total)
2022-03-11 11:35:09,137 [INFO] Base - [id:1059865964] Fetched 60 reviews (60 fetched in total)
2022-03-11 11:36:12,063 [INFO] Base - [id:1059865964] Fetched 100 reviews (100 fetched in total)
2022-03-11 11:37:08,309 [INFO] Base - [id:1059865964] Fetched 140 reviews (140 fetched in total)
2022-03-11 11:38:04,731 [INFO] Base - [id:1059865964] Fetched 180 reviews (180 fetched in total)
2022-03-11 11:39:00,995 [INFO] Base - [id:1059865964] Fetched 220 reviews (220 fetched in total)
2022-03-11 11:39:57,254 [INFO] Base - [id:1059865964] Fetched 260 reviews (260 fetched in total)
2022-03-11 11:40:53,864 [INFO] Base - [id:1059865964] Fetched 300 reviews (300 fetched in total)
2022-03-11 11:41:13,868 [ERROR] Base - Something went wrong: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='amp-api.apps.apple.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /v1/catalog/us/apps/1059865964/reviews?l=en-GB&offset=300&limit=20&platform=web&additionalPlatforms=appletv%2Cipad%2Ciphone%2Cmac (Caused by ResponseError('too many 429 error responses'))
2022-03-11 11:41:13,872 [INFO] Base - [id:1059865964] Fetched 300 reviews (300 fetched in total)
```

Comment: it may need to use proxy servers to run with different IPs. But free proxy server usually are outdated and they don't work or portals already know them and block them.